# Get dotnet pack excuted full name path and nuget push in post-build event

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I want to build my dll, and use `dotnet pack` to generate *.nupkg file. Then use `nuget push` to publish my dll.

```
dotnet pack --no-build

nuget setapikey xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx -source xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

nuget push yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy -source xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

So every time I build my project, it automatically generate *.nupkg and publish it.

But I'm stuck in publish. `nuget push` need to specify the *.nupkg, so how to get the full file name generated by `dotnet pack` marked green?
Now I have to set `yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy` every time, it's annoying.

Or is there any way to get package version, so I can build the full file name?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that `dotnet pack`'s result to a text file, and then use batch to parse that file.

```
dotnet pack > res.txt
```